# Speeding up the insertion of formulas via xlcFormula via Excel-DNA

Tags: excel-dna

I am using Excel-DNA to insert formulas into about 40k rows * 10 columns, and it is quite slow.

```
 XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcFormula, myFormula, new ExcelReference(row, row, column, column));
```

I managed to improve it dramatically by temporarily disabling the recalculation of cells on update (`XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcCalculation, 3);`), but ideally I would like to find a way to put an entire column of formulas into excel in a single operation (I am assuming this would improve the speed).

I tried passing an `object[,]` with my call to xlcFormula:

```
 XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcFormula, excelFormulas, new ExcelReference(1, lastRow, columnNumber, columnNumber));
```

but it put all the formulas into a single field (separated by semicolons). Is there a way to do what I am trying to do, or am I wasting my time on something that is impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it with screen updating also switched off `XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcEcho, false)`.

What about using the **Clipboard**? You could copy the formulae (with tabs between the columns) to the clipboard, and paste all at once into the Excel sheet. This would probably be as fast as you could get Excel to process the formula strings.

Comment: Great, thanks! I will give those a try. I notice that there is a flicker in the formula text box when inserting them, so I'm pretty sure the first option will make a difference :D

Comment: Can I put programmatically generated formulae into clipboard like that? I store templates for them in c# attributes and insert the row / column numbers at runtime (as it only knows the column that the property will be displayed in at runtime).

Comment: Disabling screen echo did the job nicely, it's really fast now. Thanks again <3

Comment: Yes, you can copy strings to the clipboard using the System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard class. Then do the paste using xlcPaste or xlcPasteSpecial. But it sounds like you're sorted out.

Comment: Nice! That might come in handy later ;)

Answer (score 4):

I also had this trouble and figured out another way to speedup formula insertion.
Try this code:

```
var formula = "=1+2";
var reference = new ExcelReference(rowFirst, rowLast, columnFirst, columnLast); // it's а rectangular area, just split up your huge area to smaler ones here
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcFormulaFill, new object[] { formula, reference } ));
```

This code is good when you want to insert the same formula into a lot of cells.
Try to use relative references in the formula.

Previous solution also works:

```
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcEcho, false)
```

... but don't forget to enable echo from time to time.

Comment: nice, I can do a whole column at once! :D